# Function to return only alpha-numeric characters from string?

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a php function that will take an input string and return a sanitized version of it by stripping away all special characters leaving only alpha-numeric.

I need a second function that does the same but only returns alphabetic characters A-Z.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Which Unicode Normalization Form are these in, and whyever would you want to do this?

Comment: When you say A-Z and 'alphanumeric', do you really mean only A-Z or do you want to match all letters from all languages, including foreign languages and obsolete scripts?

Comment: If you’e doing this so you can do an accent-insensitive string comparison, you’re doing the wrong thing.

Comment: It’s **not** just “from all languages”.  It’s English.  English uses the Latin script.  There are `unichars '\p{Latin}' '\p{Alphabetic}' '[^A-Za-z]' | wc -l` == 1192 code points that are Latin alphabetics but which are not A-Z. It is commonly held myth that ASCII is enough for English.  It’s not, and that’s why writing A-Z has a **code smell** to it.

Comment: @Mark: At present I'm only interested in English.

Comment: @Scott B: English doesn't just use the 26 letters from A-Z. For example the word résumé includes é. Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to do as this might help get you better answers.

Comment: @Mark, point taken. The function is used in a routine which takes a "primary keyword phrase" and evaluates a given block of html for appearances of the keyword phrase. The app is currently in US English, but it would be great to extend the reach.

Comment: @Scott: If you turn `résumé` into `rsum`, you’ll lose, and if you turn it into `resume`, you will retrieve too many false positives.

Comment: @tchrist: good point. What do you suggest to account for these special characters?

Comment: @Scott: If what you’re searching is in Unicode, then you should not limit people to ASCII queries. If you are using Unicode, then you should look into several things: decomposition forms in both canonical and especially also compatible modes, string comparison the Unicode Collation Algorithm with allows for not just case-insensitivity but also accent- and/or punctuation- insensitivity, string sanitizing via RFC 3454’s “Preparation for International Strings (stringprep)”, default ignorable code points, and stuff like that.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

**Warning: Note that English is not restricted to just A-Z.**

Try [this](http://ideone.com/hzXKj) to remove everything except a-z, A-Z and 0-9:

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $s);
```

If your definition of alphanumeric includes letters in foreign languages and obsolete scripts then you will need to use the Unicode character classes.

Try [this](http://ideone.com/OHfek) to leave only A-Z:

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^A-Z]+/", "", $s);
```

The reason for the warning is that words like résumé contains the letter `é` that won't be matched by this. If you want to match a specific list of letters adjust the regular expression to include those letters. If you want to match all letters, use the appropriate character classes as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: No, an alphanumeric is  `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Numeric}]`.  I forget the PCRE alphabetic property, but you can approximate  it with `[\pL\pM\pN]`.

Comment: @tchrist: I assume that because he specifically mentioned A-Z that he only wants to match that, though I admit that the question could be a lot more clear on this point. I'll ask for a clarification.

Comment: @Mark, I wasn’t arguing with the second part of your answer, although if he hasn’t canonically decomposed the string first, it won’t work right. I was arguing with the first part. Also, I try to always right regexes that work on **any** data, not just on moldy old ASCII. :) Hence the mantra that **this side of Millennium, `[A-Z]` is always wrong, *sometimes* .**

Comment: isn't `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/` the same as `/[^a-z0-9]+/i` ?

Comment: @John Isaacks: Yes, I think that's true almost always. Not sure if it's true in Turkey though. I don't have a Turkish computer on which I can test, but it depends on how PHP handles the Turkish I. Do you prefer `/.../i`?

Comment: @Mark Byers, I see.. and Yes I prefer the `i` but I have only ever has to worry about an English demographic .. I forget many people have to think about other languages. BTW I just noticed you are the highest rep'd user who has never asked 1 question. Even Jon Skeet has asked questions before!

Comment: @Mark: You’re exactly right about Turkish I’s (`İ` and `ı`).  Ranges are a problem because they often miss things.  Unicode case insensitive matches are not the same as spelled out literals, because people forget that `/i/i` matches U+130 İ, that `/k/i` matches K U+212A KELVIN SIGN, that `/f/i` matches ligatures like `ﬃ` and `ﬁ`, that `/s/i` matches `ſ` and `ß` and `ﬅ` etc. However, `/a/i` still doesn’t match `æ` nor does `/d/i` match `ǳ` (etc), so you may need to think about using the Unicode Collation Algorithm’s matchers, which are by default accent-insensitive.

Comment: I would like to keep spaces, how would I do that?

Comment: why is there a + at the end of the regexp?  Wouldn't it be ... same if you remove it?

Comment: Both links goes to a blank page. Could you fix that?

Comment: It's funny how such a simple and straight-forward question received so many completely irrelevant answers and comments (just another day on SO it seems...), Mark's answer is a wonderfully simple way to do exactly what OP asked for, nothing more, nothing less, +1

Answer (score 2):

try this to keep accentuated characters:

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^A-zÀ-ú0-9]+/", "", $s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `preg_replace`, you could always use [PHP's filter functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) using the `filter_var()` function with `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`.

Comment: Does PHP have access to the ISO Stringprep algorithm?  I know Perl and Java do.

Comment: I believe the string filter function works predominantly with 7-bit ASCII, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Please, can you tell us an explicit way of doing what the user is asking for using `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`? To my knowledge, the closest that can be archieved this way is with `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH`, but that won't leave just letters and numbers but also dots, slashes, percents and that all.

Comment: $iMycleanVar= filter_var($sStringWithNumbers, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

Comment: It looks more like a comment rather than an answer. Give a proper explanation while writing an answer.

Comment: I don't believe there is an actual FILTER_SANITIZE to alphanumeric on there, unfortunately.  Pretty major omission.

Comment: Comments require the EXACT code necessary to some the OP's question, which is a step further than hinting at functions that could be used to arrive at an answer. Please see SO [help pages](StackOverflow.com/help) for more info.