# PHP string control on chars and numbers only

Tags: php, string, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function to return only alpha-numeric characters from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199133/function-to-return-only-alpha-numeric-characters-from-string)

Starting from `$string = "hey hello 9times-%&";`

I would like to replace all the chars that are NOT numeric[0-9] or [a-z,A-Z] type.

Is there a good method to show this process control?

EDITED

i forgot that i need to leave blank space bar blank spaces, i mean:

"hey &/k" must return as "hey k" and NOT as "heyk"

Comment: replace them with nothing but leave all the original string's blank spaces

Comment: @GiantofaLannister sorry i must use remove NOT replace term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = "hey hello 9times-%&";
$string = preg_replace('/[^0-9A-Z\s]+/i', '', $string);

echo $string;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `preg_replace`:

```
$clean = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-z\s]/i','',$input);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/[^ \w]+/i', '', $string);
```

That will work as well. See the [codepad example](http://codepad.org/zuzjvo7n).