# Best way to Filter Username for Database in PHP

Tags: php

What is the best way to filter username in PHP :-

I have everything that I need working, but I would like to verify that a username entered during the registration only contains alphanumeric characters. So how could I take a variable, say $username, and ensure that it contained only alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Could you add some code to your question?

Comment: Your probably looking for a regular expression like the one described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores.

Comment: This regex expression may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199133/function-to-return-only-alpha-numeric-characters-from-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?
if (ctype_alnum($user)) {
   //YAY THE STRING IS ALPHANUMERIC!
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ctype_alnum`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) function:

```
if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
    // here, $username is alphanumeric
}
```