# PHP - Path Manipulation / Input Validation

Tags: php, security, validation, path-manipulation

I ran a Gray Box Assessment test for an application i developed and i have some vulnerabilities, specific a Path Manipulation in the Input Validation Category.

I have in my code:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"contacts_load/" . $fileName)) {
    if ($import = fopen ("contacts_load/" . $fileName,"r")) {
```

and:

```
unlink("contacts_load/" . $fileName);
```

The problem is in `contacts_load/`.

Below you are going to find some information about this:

> **Description:** Allowing user input to control paths used in filesystem operations could enable an attacker to access or modify otherwise protected system resources.
>
> **Specific Scenario:**
>
> Path manipulation errors occur when the following two conditions are met:
>
> 1. An attacker can specify a path used in an operation on the
>      filesystem.
> 2. By specifying the resource, the attacker gains a capability that
>          would not otherwise be permitted.
>
> **For example**, the program may give the attacker the ability to overwrite the specified file or run with a configuration controlled by the attacker.

How can i prevent the path manipulation for this specific scenario?

Comment: Where does `$fileName` come from?

Comment: From here: `$fileName = Date("YmdHis")."_".$_FILES["file"]["name"];` but the issue is in the path (`contacts_load/`).

Comment: `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` already contains the `basename` of the filename provided in the request.

Comment: The issue is with `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`.  It's user supplied and is a path/file.

Comment: You are right, i was confuse, the issue is with the filename, because the attacker could provide a file name such as "../../tomcat/conf/server.xml" and cause a problem in the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with `contacts_load/`. The user cannot modify it.

I do recommend you sanitize `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` though. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5199183/1234256) should be helpful.

Comment: The issue is in the file path, not in the filename.

Comment: @JuanSedano The user cannot control it. What concerns do you have?

Comment: You are right, i was confuse, the issue is with the filename, because the attacker could provide a file name such as "../../tomcat/conf/server.xml" and cause a problem in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess file?

```
# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes
```