# Using regex to search the key in an array and return the value - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Suppose there is an array

```
$data = array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2",
    "key3" => "value3"
);
```

And there is a string which may contain one of the keys in this array. And I want the value of this key in the array.

For example, the string is `"**^%$key1^&*"` which contains `"key1"`. What I want to do is to return the `value1`.

---

This example maybe better for understanding:

```
$fruits = array(
    "apple" => "red",
    "avocado" => "green",
    "orange" => "orange"
);
```

When the input is `"Gala apple"` I want the output to be `"red"`

What I can think for now is using foreach.

```
$str = "Gala apple";

foreach($fruits as $k=>$v) {
    if(preg_match('/'.$k.'/i', $str))
        return $v;
}
```

This code works.

But... is there any method can avoid the loop?

Comment: Are alphanumerical characters the only ones you want to keep in the string? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659025/how-to-remove-non-alphanumeric-characters

Comment: @chris85 that was a bad example, I have updated the question and I just want the string to match the key in array.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) ?

```
$data = array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2",
    "key3" => "value3",
);

$str = "!&!%key3!@#$$";
for($data as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos($str, $key) !== false) {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is just general idea :) using strpos instead of regexp

Comment: @nerdlyist yes, "may contain" means if the key presented in the string, so **^%$key13^&* contains key1 whether you use regexp or strpos

Answer (score 0):

If the only alphanumerics chars in the key string are the valid key, you can strip the other chars using a function such as `$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $s);` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199133/function-to-return-only-alpha-numeric-characters-from-string) SO post.

If you know the key, you can directly access  the value using this syntax:
 `$array[$key]`

Sample code:

```
$array = array(
    "key1" => "val1",
    "key2" => "val2",
    "key3" => "val3",
    "key4" => "val4",
    );
echo $array["key2"];
```

This will echo `val2`.

To verify if a key exists, you may use `isset($array[$key])` or the `array_key_exists($key, $array)` method.